# Extjs show link on a single word

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How can I show a link in a single word like so :

```
 Click **here** (link only when clicking on the word here)
```

I manage to create a link component with Extjs like this (I'm using Extjs 4.1), but the problem is that link is on the whole phrase.

```
    {
        xtype : 'component',
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'a',
            target: '_blank',
            href: 'help/GUI_help.html',
            html: 'Help on GUI.'
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the simplest solution:

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    html: 'Help on <a href="help/GUI_help.html" target="_blank">GUI</a>'
}
```

Comment: Thanks I realized it was easier this way after posting my question, and so this is how I managed to solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

You've probably thought of this before, but I would say do this :

```
},{
    xtype: 'component',
    autoEl: {
        html: 'Click '
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'component',
    autoEl: {
        tag: 'a',
        target: '_blank',
        href: 'help/GUI_help.html',
        html: 'Here.'
    }
}
```